# Telling First Order Linear vs Non Linear ODE from its Slope Field

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Is it possible to distinguish between a first order linear and non linear ODE just from its slope field? In autonomous vs non-autonomous, you can easily tell from whether the slope varies with $x$. I can not think of patterns that would distinguish $y' +p(t)y = q(t)$ from $y\ = f(t,y)$... is this generally the case?

Comment: For a linear system the slopes for constant $t$ will change at a constant rate. Looking at a column of little tangent lines the slopes should change a constant amount between each one.